# Firebase - Rule always denies requests

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, firebase-security

I am starting to restrict the access to my Firebase Database. So far I have three collections where I simply want to return true for testing purposes.

[image]

I did it like this

```
  rules_version = '2';
    service cloud.firestore {
      match /databases/{database}/documents {
        match /devices/{device} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
        
        match /users/{user} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
        
        match /groups/{group} {
            allow read, write: if true;
        }
      }
    }
```

When I try to test this, I can't access the data no matter what. It gets always denied.

[image]

Comment: Correct me if i'm wrong but i think you're referring to cloud firestore instead of firebase-realtime-database?

Comment: yes thats true, its the firestore

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your rules are correct, I see the issue is how you are using the playground,

In the textbox just enter something like
`/devices/yourdeviceId`

Answer (score 0):

When you use the console simulator to test your rules, the field for the document to test should only contain the path of the document to get, using only the names of specific collections and document IDs.  If you're trying to test document "foo" in collection "devices", then your path should be "/devices/foo".  Don't enter the full match path, and don't use any wildcards - you should refere to an actual document in the same way that you would refer to it in your app code.